# Matching line to multiple regex patterns

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a file which I need to validate. The line can be of one of the following formats:

```
<String>:<Number>:<String>:<String>    <Number>
<String>:<Number>:<String>    <Number>
<String>:<Number>    <Number>
<String>    <Number>
```

I am planning to use multiple regexes to match the line. Is this a good way of going about it?

```
while ((line = file.readLine()) != null) {
    boolean match = false;
    if (line.matches(pattern1)) {
        match = true;
    }
    if (line.matches(pattern2)) {
        match = true;
    }
    if (line.matches(pattern3)) {
        match = true;
    }
    if (line.matches(pattern4)) {
        match = true;
    }
    if (!match) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format")
    }
}
```

I appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would merge the patterns into a single regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<String>(?::<Number>(?::<String>){0,2})?    <Number>");
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/eV7tE5/1).